# unknown jquery method used in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was just going through the source of `modal.js` and came across the following line of code:

```
var e = $.Event('shown.bs.modal', { relatedTarget: _relatedTarget })
```

It is quite confusing to understand what `e` is being defined as, as I have never seen such a construct in JS/Jquery. I tried Googling `jQuery.Event()` and `$.Event`, but all i get in the jQquery doc's is [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/), which isn't leading me anywhere.

The line in concern is [line 50](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L50) in `modal.js`.

If I run `console.log(_relatedTarget);` i get the following HTML object:

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
```

I didn't want to post an overly complicated question, so I am just posting the relevant line of code. I know the piece of code I have provided uses `object` and looking at it might not give you an outright overview of what that line is doing, but if somebody can tell me what vaguely that line of code is doing or seems to be doing, i could go look up. As of now, I am stuck on this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the [`Event Object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

> Query's event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

Bootstrap is just creating a proper jQuery Event that is fired later on, in this case when the modal is shown.

Comment: ! Awesome , a great  resource . Thanks